# Search Function Implementation in Binary Search Tree

Tags: c++, search, binary-search-tree

I have implemented a function "searchkey" in order to return a node in a binary search tree if the key is present but it is returning the root node. I have added a minimal reproducible code.
While the same iterative method works. Also which would be the better way to implement this recursive or iterative.

```
template<class T>
    class Node{
    public:
        T m_data;  
        Node<T>* m_left;
        Node<T>* m_right;
    
        Node(T data){
             m_data=data;
             m_left=nullptr;
             m_right=nullptr;
         }
    };
    
    template<class T>
    class bst {
    private:
        Node<T>* root;
    
    public:
        bst() { root = nullptr; }
        ~bst() { deltree(root); }
        void addnode(Node<T>* node, T data) {
            
            if(this->root == nullptr) {
                Node<T>* new_node= new Node<T>(data);
                this->root = new_node;
            } else if(data > node->m_data) {
                if(node->m_right != nullptr) {
                    addnode(node->m_right, data);
                } else {
                    Node<T>* new_node = new Node<T>(data);
                    node->m_right = new_node;
                }
            } else if(data < node->m_data) {
                if(node->m_left != nullptr) {
                    addnode(node->m_left, data);
                } else {
                    Node<T>* new_node = new Node<T>(data);
                    node->m_left = new_node;
                }
            }
        }
        void addnode(T data) { addnode(this->root, data); }
    
         Node<T>* searchkey(T data) { 
            return searchkey(data,this->root);
    }
    
            Node<T>* searchkey(T data, Node<T> *node) {
        if (node == nullptr) { // <-- check if node is null
            return node;
        } else if (data == node->m_data) {
            return node;
        } else if (node->m_data > data) {
            searchkey(data, node->m_left);
        } else if (node->m_data < data) {
            searchkey(data, node->m_right);
        }
        return node;
    }
    
    void deltree(Node<T>* node) {
            if(node) {
                deltree(node->m_left);
                deltree(node->m_right);
                delete node;
            }
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are missing a few `return` statements in your search function. Also, the test for `data == node->m_data` isn't needed. The fallback `return` at the end of the function means that a match is found if you `return` when doing the recursive calls.

```
Node<T>* searchkey(T data, Node<T> *node) {
    if (node == nullptr) { // <-- check if node is null
        return node;
    } else if (node->m_data > data) {
        return searchkey(data, node->m_left);
    } else if (node->m_data < data) {
        return searchkey(data, node->m_right);
    }
    return node; // match found
}
```

In your original code, you called `searchkey` but did not return the value it returned. The function instead continued to return the same `node` that was given as an argument to the function, yielding the wrong result in all cases except when searching for the value stored in the `root` node.

An alternative view:

```
Node<T>* searchkey(T data, Node<T> *node) {
    if (node != nullptr) {
        if (node->m_data > data) {
            node = searchkey(data, node->m_left);
        } else if (node->m_data < data) {
            node = searchkey(data, node->m_right);
        } // else { here we know that node->m_data == data }
    }
    return node; // nullptr or the matching Node* is returned
}
```

> Also which would be the better way to implement this recursive or iterative.

There's no definite answer. If you are likely to store many values, so the search depth becomes large, you don't want recursive calls because you may then get a stack overflow.

Comment: Though this works fine can you please explain how is this working ?

Comment: I am a bit rusty in recursion so i would like to ask how this recursive call knows that we have matched the key as we are not making any equality comparison between nodes value and the key provided.

Comment: @Tushar It's just the only option left. We've established that `node->m_data` is neither less nor greater than `data` - so it's equal. I'll add a note in the alternative view about it.

Comment: Okay i had this thought but was doubtful about this! so actually what I can figure out is that the searchkey() would return a node to its recursive caller and that will call its ancestors and thus we get the node.

Comment: @Tushar Yes, it becomes a call-chain where the leaf-node will either return a matching `Node*` or `nullptr`. This returned value is then propagated upwards until it's returned to the initial caller of `searchkey()`.